# Node : Not able to pass a huge array as parameter to a function

Tags: node.js

I have an array with 15,000 objects. I am not able to pass the array to a function as a parameter. The function doesn't seem to be getting called. When I reduced the sample with 3 objects, the code seems to be working perfectly.

```
var rest = require('restler');

processData() {
    rest.get("http://someUrl/data.json").on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            callback(result);
        } else {
            console.log(result.length); //Prints exact count in either cases
            startProcessing(result);
        }
    });
}

function startProcessing(jsonData) {
    console.log('processor called'); // Called when jsonData.length = 3. Fails for 15,000
}
```

Strange but what can be the problem here?

Comment: will be hard to tell if you wont show us the code

Comment: I've updated my question with the code sample

Comment: Is the call getting into the XHR callback?  Where is `rest` defined?  Is that node.js native?  I haven't heard of it.  Which function doesn't seem to be getting called, the `rest.get(callback)` callback function or just `startProcessing()`?

Comment: I'm using an npm package called restler to call REST API's

Comment: Note that generally there's a maximum size for a GET requests to avoid receiving huge payloads that would cripple the server. Are you sure the middleware doesn't have a size limit.

Comment: console.log(result.length); displays the exact count in either cases. I am assuming it doesn't have a limit since the count is correct.

Comment: @adeneo the json would be the get *response*, not the get *request*, so 3 or 15,000 wouldn't be dependent upon the HTTP method. It's *possible* that enough memory could be tied up that it would take a "long time" (for certain values of "long") to pass that much data around, but seems unlikely. It wouldn't flat out "fail" without a catchable error.  Odds are there's something else going on, not visible in the code you've provided here.